# Windows 8 Automatic Page File Size vs Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, memory, virtual-memory, pagefile

I've noticed that Windows 8 sets smaller page files by default. Windows 7 systems seem to create a page file the size of the RAM (eg 4GB of RAM means that Windows makes a 4GB page file). In Windows 8 (and 10), the page file is a fraction of the RAM size- a PC with 2GB of RAM and a PC with 4GB of RAM both have a 704mb page file by default.

What is the reasoning behind this? How does Windows decide, and why is it smaller than in older versions of Windows? I haven't found much about this online at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the new dump [setting "Automatic dump" in Windows 8](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/09/12/windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-automatic-memory-dump.aspx).

> The “System Managed” page file has been updated to reduce the page
>   file size on disk, primarily for small SSDs but will also benefit
>   servers with large amounts or ram.
>
> The “Automatic memory dump” is not really a new memory dump type. In
>   previous versions of Windows, we already have Mini, Kernel, and
>   Complete memory dump options. The Automatic memory dump option
>   produces a Kernel memory dump, **the difference is when you select
>   Automatic it allows the SMSS process to reduce the page file smaller
>   than the size of RAM.**